# jquery cannot stop propagation

Tags: jquery, css

I have read almost every similar post but cannot figure out what is going wrong in my case.
I have a **file** icon on my toolbar and when be clicked, a `type=file` input tag will open in order to open local files.

```js
    $('#file').click(function() {
      $('#openFiles').css('visibility', 'visible');
    });

    $('#openFiles').on('hover', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```css
#file:hover {
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#file {
  float: left;
  width: 24px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 4.4%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-image: url('public/images/file.png');
}
#openFiles {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="file">
  <input type="file" id="openFiles" name="files[]" multiple />
</div>
```

My problem: hovering over #openFiles causes both #openFiles and #file to transform despite of stopPropagation. Any idea?

Comment: how about you create another DIV next to input. have it absolute 100% × 100%. and do transform/click of that. then you won't have parent-child issues.

Comment: I will give it a try, but question remains

Comment: edit your question to standard view

Comment: Fix: `#openFiles { position: relative; /* margin-top: 60px; */ visibility: hidden; width: 24px; } too confuse css lol ... Let's Go Learn http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animate_buttons.asp

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i understand the problem but there seem to be a couple of misconceptions in your code.

The `e.stopPropagation` affects only the javascript side of things. It will not prevent a CSS event from propagating.

Secondly, since you scale (*through `transform`*) the container element `#file` it will affect all its contents as well, namely the `#openFiles` element.